# Serde json value omit properties on None

Tags: rust, serde

Given the following JsonValue:

```
let mut schema = json!({
    "level": "strict",
    "rule": {}
});
```

Where we would dynamically insert values to this JsonValue

```
let value: json!({
    "type": property.r#type,
    "minLength": property.min_length,
    "maxLength": property.max_length,
    "enum": property.r#enum
});

schema["rule"]
    .as_object_mut()
    .unwrap()
    .insert(
        String::from(property.name), 
        value
    );

// Struct for Property
#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct SchemaDocumentProperty
{
    pub name: String,
    pub r#type: Option<String>,
    pub min_length: Option<u32>,
    pub max_length: Option<u32>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub r#enum: Option<Vec<String>>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub items: Option<SchemaDocumentPropertyArray>
}
```

The current output is the following where `minLength`, `maxLength` and `enum` are None:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "minLength": null,
    "maxLength": null,
    "enum": null
}
```

My desired output:

```
{
    "type": "string"
}
```

I want to omit all of the None values from the JsonValue macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a `Value` struct instead of using the `json!` macro:

```rust
#[derive(Default, Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Value
{
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub r#type: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub min_length: Option<u32>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub max_length: Option<u32>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub r#enum: Option<Vec<String>>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub items: Option<SchemaDocumentPropertyArray>
}
```

If you need a `serde_json::Value` use the [`to_value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.to_value.html) method:

```rust
let value = Value { ... };
let json_value = serde_json::to_value(value).expect("Valid json value");
```

Comment: I thought of doing it this way, however the ```.as_object_mut().unwrap().insert(k, v)``` only accepts JsonValue on `v`. The following is thrown: mismatched types
expected enum `serde_json::Value`, found struct `SchemaDocumentProperty`rustc (E0308)

Comment: @itsezc check the update on how to transform a serializable type to a Value

Comment: you may want to use `serde_with` crate's `#[skip_serializing_none]` once for the whole struct, instead of adding multiple `skip_serializing_if`. See https://docs.rs/serde_with/3.4.0/serde_with/attr.skip_serializing_none.html